# How to place div on canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing some JS which put div over canvas element, but div hides under the canvas element. I tweaked z-index and deferred execution, but it makes no effect. How to do that?

Here is my code(doesn't works as intended).

https://jsfiddle.net/gbqvosnw/

I'd like to put div element on canvas using pure javascript.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  a().then(() => {
    b();
  });
}

const b = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.setAttribute("id", "div-on-canvas");
    d.style.setProperty("position", "absolute");
    d.style.setProperty("top", "50px");
    d.style.setProperty("left", "50px");
    d.style.setProperty("width", "50px");
    d.style.setProperty("height", "50px");
    d.style.setProperty("background", "blue");
    d.style.setProperty("z-index", 2);
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(d);
    resolve();
  });
}

const a = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var ca = document.createElement("canvas");
    ca.setAttribute("id", "canvas");
    ca.style.setProperty("position", "relative");
    ca.style.setProperty("z-index", 1);
    ca.width = 150;
    ca.height = 150;
    var co = ca.getContext("2d");
    co.fillStyle = "red";
    co.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(ca);
    resolve();
  });
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="container"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Both the element has same `z-index`. Give a higher `z-index` for elements which has to be on top.

Comment: Canvas elements can't contain child elements (well, they can as a fallback for old browsers, but the element won't be displayed if the canvas is supported), did you mean to append the element to the container rather than the canvas?

Comment: Place your div outside the canvas element. canvas cannot have children.

Comment: @shri-hari-l Thanks. I edited z-index, but it works no effect. Fixed above.

Comment: @DBS they _can_ contain child elements - but same as with an `iframe`, those only provide the _fallback content_ the browser is supposed to display if it _can't_ understand `canvas`.

Comment: @CBroe Haha, indeed, you caught me before I made the edit.

Comment: @DBS Thanks much. I misunderstanded that canvas element can contain child element. I'll go with adding div not to canvas but container element.

Answer (score 0):

As @DBS comments, Canvas elements cannot contain child elements (as a fallback for older browsers they can contain child elements, but if canvas is supported the elements will not be displayed).

Adding the element to the container works as intended.

Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/gbqvosnw/1/

```js
window.onload = () => {
  a().then(() => {
    b();
  });
}

const b = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var d = document.createElement("div");
      d.setAttribute("id", "div-on-canvas");
      d.style.setProperty("position", "absolute");
      d.style.setProperty("top", "50px");
      d.style.setProperty("left", "50px");
      d.style.setProperty("width", "50px");
      d.style.setProperty("height", "50px");
      d.style.setProperty("background", "blue");
      d.style.setProperty("z-index", 2);
      document.getElementById("container").appendChild(d);
      resolve();
  });
}

const a = () => {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
     var ca = document.createElement("canvas");
     ca.setAttribute("id", "canvas");
     ca.style.setProperty("position", "relative");
     ca.style.setProperty("z-index", 1);
     ca.width = 150;
     ca.height = 150;
     var co = ca.getContext("2d");
     co.fillStyle = "red";
     co.fillRect(0,0,150,150);
     document.getElementById("container").appendChild(ca);
     resolve();
  });
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="container"></div>
</main>
```